Label on Packaging Surface / Texture Problems
I have a question about my label on a packaging. I created the packaging myself and now I want to put my label on the front of the packaging. Unfortunately, it's always distorted and doesn't look nice. The surface isn't perfectly flat, but I think it should still be represented somewhat nicely. I created a mesh plane and used a text image as material. Then I tried to get it onto the surface of the packaging using the Shrinkwrap Modifier. However, the result doesn't look good.
Another question is about the packaging itself: there are two vertical stripes on the left and right with different material textures. I can't get rid of them; could this possibly be due to incorrect vertices?
And my last question is, once I render the image, the result is completely white and totally overexposed. I probably have a setting that leads to this error. However, I can't find the solution.

I'll attach the Blender file and would be grateful for any help, as I've been struggling with these issues for several hours. Thank you very much.


Hello, please pack your image (File > External Data > Pack Resources) before saving and sharing

@moonboots Okay, I also didn´t know. However I did now and edited again. I think it should packed and updated now.

For the over-exposition you have a light that is hidden for preview but visible for render, disable it. For the Shrinkwrap you could switch to the Wrap Method > Project, move it towards the pack until it sticks to its surface and play with the Offset. That said, you could have made this sticker part of the object material. Also don't forget to right click > Shade Smooth to smooth the shading.

As for the vertical lines it's because of the bad topology, rework it a bit, for example here you have overlapping faces:


Wow, thank you for the detailed answers!! I will try it (I am still beginner). However this is very helpfull!
